# Why is Monero more sensitive to reorganizations than Bitcoin?

Tags: hard-fork

According to [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1205/138) Monero (CryptoNote) is more sensitive to reorganizations than Bitcoin. What specifically is the reason to support this statement?

Comment: The answer on that link has the answer to this question after the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was touched on in another question here [Why was the block time changed from 1 to 2 minutes?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5/why-was-the-block-time-changed-from-1-to-2-minutes) , and linked to this explanation. https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/2401/increasing-the-block-time

Unfortunately smooth doesn't specifically spell it out, but my best guess is that ring signatures make reorganisations more difficult, which would make sense.