# When did Monero switch to 2 minute blocks?

Tags: hard-fork, block-inverval, hydrogen-helix

When Monero was launched, it used a 1 minute block time.  In the question [Why was the block time changed from 1 to 2 minutes?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5/why-was-the-block-time-changed-from-1-to-2-minutes/6#6), reasons for the switch were discussed. When, however, did this switch actually occur?

I am wondering both the block height and date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The change was introduced with the [Monero v0.9.0 "Hydrogen Helix" release](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.9.0) on the 1st of Jan, 2016 however it did not take effect until the [20th of March, 2016 at block 1009827](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L91) as explained by user3603. More details about the original Hydrogen Helix release can be [found here](https://getmonero.org/2016/01/01/monero-0.9.0-hydrogen-helix-released.html)

Answer (score 8):

The change occured at hard fork 2, on block 1009827 (see the table near the top of src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp). This was in march 2016.